# Blog module fatal error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, blogs

I'm new in Magento and I tried to instal a module of blog in my store, the only thing that i know is that the magento version is 1.7 and the blog version is 1.0. If you don't know how to help me, could give me an idea of how can i search about it at web?

Fatal error: Class 'Blog_Block_Manage_Blog_Edit_Form' not found in /var/www/html/store/var/cache/ew/files/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/a98f181a3dc22489d2af4466edf817fa.php on line 491 Call Stack: 0.0004 631752 1. {main}() /var/www/html/store/index.php:0 0.0229 3334304 2. Mage::run() /var/www/html/store/index.php:87 0.0277 3551736 3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run() /var/www/html/store/app/Mage.php:683 1.2110 6518712 4. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_FrontOverriddenClass->dispatch() /var/www/html/store/app/code/local/Extendware/EWPageCache/Controller/Override/Mage/Core/Varien/Front.php:32 1.2179 6655808 5. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_StandardOverriddenClass->match() /var/www/html/store/var/cache/ew/files/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front/8b52e7f857fef0572cf21f0a3352151f.php:176 1.2197 6749312 6. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch() /var/www/html/store/var/cache/ew/files/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard/088bf81233af8a733a03eb4d9a3bcae0.php:250 3.0816 11684784 7. Blog_Manage_BlogController->editAction() /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:419 3.4550 20040984 8. Mage_Core_Model_LayoutOverriddenClass->createBlock() /var/www/html/store/app/code/local/myWebStore/Blog/controllers/Manage/BlogController.php:63 3.4878 20287184 9. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout() /var/www/html/store/var/cache/ew/files/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/a98f181a3dc22489d2af4466edf817fa.php:456 3.4879 20287184 10. Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout() /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:238 3.4879 20287360 11. Mage_Core_Model_LayoutOverriddenClass->createBlock() /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php:82 3.4879 20287656 12. Mage_Core_Model_LayoutOverriddenClass->_getBlockInstance() /var/www/html/store/var/cache/ew/files/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/a98f181a3dc22489d2af4466edf817fa.php:437

Comment: The config XML is maldefined Magento tries to load a module file from the core directories. At least it looks like it. I would suggest to contact the people who offer the blog extension, without knowledge of how the module is set up and coded it'll be hard to be of any help to you. Have you checked if the extension is compatible with Magento 1.7?

Comment: Yes, it is compatible, i installed this module once before and it worked well. I'll try to discover the name of the extension, contact them and try to fix. This was very helpful, thank you so much!

I'll update this post with news.